# Create 3D map in angular application using open layers and ol-cesium

Tags: angular, openlayers, openlayers-3, cesiumjs

I want to creating this project in angular but getting error when we import **olcesium** in .ts file after install npm ol-cesium.

```html
<html>
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.70/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.70/Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol-cesium@2.11.3/css/olcs.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol-cesium@2.11.3/dist/olcesium.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #olCesMap {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #btnSwitchMap {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 50px;
            z-index: 2;
            padding: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>  
<body>
    <div id="olCesMap">
        <button id="btnSwitchMap" onclick="cesViewer.setEnabled(!cesViewer.getEnabled());">Switch 2D/3D</button>
    </div>
    <script defer>
        var controls = ol.control.defaults({
            rotate: true,
            rotateOptions: {
                tipLabel: "Reset rotation. \nUse Alt+Shift+Drag to rotate the map."
            }
        });
        var interactions = ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: true, pinchRotate: true });

        // Declaring Zoom level to further view
        var zoom = 3;
        // Declaring Map center
        var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-96.41778916767144, 39.90201978025539]);
        
        var worldImagery = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
            maxZoom: 19
            })
        });
        worldImagery.set('name', 'tileLayer');


      
        //Map Creation
        var map = new ol.Map({
            controls: controls,
            //interactions: interactions,
            target: 'olCesMap',
            layers: [worldImagery, new ol.layer.Image({
                extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
            })],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: center,
                zoom: zoom
            })
        });
        //Cesium Viewer constructed based on Ol.Map
        var cesViewer = new olcs.OLCesium({
            map: map,
            sceneOptions: {
                mapProjection: new Cesium.WebMercatorProjection()
            }
        });
        //Cesium Viewer scene
        var scene = cesViewer.getCesiumScene();
        //Cesium Viewer enable
        cesViewer.setEnabled(false);

        //Cesium Viewer depthtest
        scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to creating this project in angular but getting error when we import **olcesium** in .ts file after install npm ol-cesium.

want to configure this project in angular application and also use this cdn link through npm.
suggest me how we can make this because when we create then getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Someone did a good job in [here](https://github.com/pzaenger/angular-openlayers)

I just add second item in [`tileSources`](https://github.com/pzaenger/angular-openlayers/blob/master/src/app/services/geo.service.ts#L24) as same as your [`arcgisonline`](https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services) tile source.

```
  tileSources = [
    { name: 'None', source: null },
    { name: 'arcgison', source: new OsmSource({ url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}' }) },
    { name: 'OSM', source: new OsmSource() },
    { name: 'Stamen', source: new StamenSource({ layer: 'toner' }) }
  ];
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Please read my question what I want, I want to create 3D map view in open layers using OL-Cesium

Comment: that example is use [ol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol) library. It is different with olcesium?

Comment: Can you please send full code

Comment: and I want to Create 3D map in open layers

Comment: You can get the full source code from github in my answer here link, by `git clone https://github.com/pzaenger/angular-openlayers.git` or download zip file form it.  It seems not support 3D map button not as same `olcesium`. I will try to find a solution with `olcesium` later.

Comment: Ok thank you I'am waiting for your reply

Comment: Sorry, It is out of my scope. I just find one article , [A Simple Guide to OpenLayers in Angular](https://medium.com/runic-software/a-simple-guide-to-openlayers-in-angular-b10f6feb3df1)

Comment: thank you but its not my solution